# Scrapy runs into endless loop due to process_links

Tags: scrapy

I am using scrapy 2.1.0 and want to add parameters via link_filtering to each request. This works but I do run into an endless loop as the duplicate filter seems to be affected through this.

```
rules = (
    Rule(
        LinkExtractor(
            allow=['^(example)?\/(?!ratgeber)[a-z-]+\/(\?p=\d+)?$'],
            restrict_xpaths=(['//div[@class="sidebar--categories-navigation"]', # only navi pannel
                              '//div[contains(@class,"panel--paging")]/a']), # include pagination         
        ), 
        follow=True,
        process_links='link_filtering',                    
        callback= 'parse_item'
    ),
)
```

add link filtering:

```
# get max amount of results per category and add n=x results to url
def link_filtering(self, links):
    for link in links:
        if re.match('.*\?.*',link.url) is None: #add all parameters if there are none
            link.url = "%s?p=1&followSearch=10000&o=1&n=1000" % link.url
        else:  # add max amount of results to pagination
            link.url = "%s&followSearch=10000&o=1&n=1000" % link.url
    return links
```

The crawler will continue spidering the same URLs over and over again. How can I prevent that and keep the added parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`from w3lib.url import canonicalize_url`

then

`link.url = canonicalize_url(link.url)`

will this help ?

and keep the original return

Comment: Isn't that exactly my link_filtering method?

Comment: instead of return use generators.is not quite similar . you return each link is valid not a list of links

Comment: i didn't checked all your code only i noticed this part

Comment: Seems to be the same result? I replaced the return with "yield link" and it is still caught in the loop.

Comment: if this change with canonicalize_url is not working i am out of ideas for now

Comment: and have too look on the first rules